Проверка доступности сервера\сервиса и на основании этого запуск Powershell
У меня есть скрипт, который выполняется по расписанию.
Хочу добавить к нему проверку доступности сервиса или сервера и чтобы на основании доступности скрипт или запускался или останавливался.
Написал в заголовке:
(Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName  MYSERVER).Where({ $_.State -eq 'active' })  
(Get-Service Dhcpserver -ComputerName MYSERVER).Where({ $_.Status -eq 'Running' }) 
Не могу понять, как запустить скрипт на основании данных, что служба Running или на основании State=Active?

Чтобы проверить статус службы, сделал следующее:
$accept = ((Get-Service Dhcpserver -ComputerName MYSERVER)).Where({ $_.Status -eq 'Running' }) 

if ($accept)
{
    скрипт
} 


if ((Get-Service Dhcpserver -ComputerName MYSERVER).Status -eq 'Running'){                 скрипт }

Спасибо за оптимизацию.
Теперь ищу способ проверить все скопы на статус "актив" и только в этом случае запуска скрипта, тут вообще как в стену упёрся.

Что-нибудь вроде этого if ((Get-DhcpServerv4Scope).state -notcontains 'Inactive'){скрипт}
